# Does Neo4j AuraDB (GCP managed service) have CMEK support?

Tags: security, neo4j

I am reading the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/cloud/aura/) for Neo4j AuraDB and I cannot find if it supports Customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK). Does it support CMEK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No, AuraDB currently doesn't support CMEK.
Long Answer: [Aura Enterprise : How is my data encrypted at rest ?](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/4411343700115-Aura-Enterprise-How-is-my-data-encrypted-at-rest-)